# What do you use to support asymmetrical Paths with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, rewrite, url, url-routing

My customers want me to deliver a solution that allows asymmetrical path's with SharePoint.  I know this is not officially supported from Microsoft, but it seems like a reasonable request.

I'm trying to shorten my URL paths for country domains.  This is a common technique used for Search Engine Optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True, asymmetrical paths aren't supported by SharePoint. The best supported option is [configure alternate access mappings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288609.aspx).

I don't know enough about ISA or other proxy options but I would have thought this route is your best option. As long as its thoroughly tested this should work OK.

**Update:** There's also a programmatic option I came across: [ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 routing with SharePoint 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122175/using-asp-net-3-5-sp1-routing-with-sharepoint-2007). However I'd be very careful about whether this is supported by Microsoft.

Also there is a lot you can do with other SEO techniques. I think you already know all this but for other people some good resources are:

- [Imtech SharePoint SEO slugs](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/optimize-publishing-pages-search-engines-imtech-sharepoint-seo-slugs-feature/)
- [MOSS SEO](http://www.mossseo.com/) (including info on a SiteMap Generator)
- [How to Optimize WCM Sites for Search Engines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721591.aspx)
- [Removing /Pages from URLs](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/semantic-urls-in-moss-2007-imtech-sharepoint-semantic-urls-free-feature/) (Imtech again)

Comment: I agree with Alex.  True asymmetric paths are not supported, though you can do all of the hostname, port, and protocol remapping you want.

ISA Server 2006 has built-in support specifically for publishing SharePoint sites, and it is by far the most fully-featured option out there.  TechNet has a great "how to" article with supporting examples/information here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261814.aspx.

Another (free) option for URL re-writing is the SharePoint Hosters Kit on CodePlex: http://www.codeplex.com/SharePointHosters.  It introduces an HttpModule to re-write URLs.

Comment: One more option, since it's probably the only real option that will work for your specific scenario: redirects.  Todd Klindt has a great article on the topic: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=48

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'm well versed in AAM and SharePoint.  I'm hoping to find some stories of how people use Reverse Proxy Technology to rewrite URLs based on well defined rules.